# Conversor de texto Gift format para moodle em linguagem Java

Tags: java

Sou iniciante com programação principalmente em Java, tenho dúvidas de como trabalhar com String em um arraylist, precisaria acessar cada linha no texto e modificalo. Resposta com asterisco * são corretas

**Entrada de texto que o usuário digita:**
O que há entre laranja e verde no espectro. Assinale a alternativa ?

*amarelo
vermelho
azul
verde
roxo

**Saída de texto após converter:**
::Título:: O que há entre laranja e verde no espectro. Assinale a alternativa?{

*amarelo
~vermelho
~azul
~verde
~roxo
}

Não sei como posso iniciar a conversão neste arraylist

```
    List<String> giftFormat = new ArrayList<String>();
 
    giftFormat.add(txtEntradaDeTexto.getText());
    
    // Percorrer arraylist, realizando a formatação
    for (String integer: giftFormat) {
        
    }
```

Comment: Explica melhor o que pretendes.

Comment: Seria uma conversão de texto, pegar as string e colocar em um array ou arraylist, ao final da 1ª linha coloque abertura de chaves ( { ), dentro das chaves após encontra o asterisco (resposta correta) troque por sinal de igual ( = ) e as demais alternativas coloque sinal de til ( ~ ) que seria as resposta correta, e abaixo feche a chave ( } )

Comment: Cada linha é um valor na lista inicial?

Comment: Isso cada linha seria um valor, primeira linha a pergunta, as outras linhas as alternativas e a ultima linha chave ( } )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se percebi o que querias tenta isto.

```java
List<String> giftFormat = //...

for (int i = 0; i < giftFormat.size(); i++) {
    String linha = giftFormat.get(i);
    if (i == 0)
        giftFormat.set(i, linha + "{");
    else if(linha.charAt(0) == '*')
        giftFormat.set(i, linha.replace("*", "="));
    else
        giftFormat.set(i, "~" + linha);
}
giftFormat.add("}");
```

Comment: Deu certo, fiz um ajuste e deu pra converter, muito abrigado ajudou bastante